# Navigate to another page at OnNavigatedTo?

Tags: c++, events, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

Why does the method [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702396) not work when called in the [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) event of this page?

Is this behavior reproducible for you?

Any ideas how to avoid this problem?

```c
void LockScreenPage::OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    //if user has no PIN protection
    this->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(AnotherPage::typeid));

    //else verify PIN
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer I'm afraid but why would you do this instead of just navigating to the page you want?

Comment: The app I'm working on has a lock screen which is opened when starting the app. If the user has no PIN protection enabled I'm navigating to another page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the right behavior I am now using the dispatcher:

```
    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this] () {
        this->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(AnotherPage::typeid));
    }));
```